# Converting list to dataframe from knoema package in R

Tags: r

I am looking to extract data using the `knoema` package in R. I have the following code script which pulls South African bond yield data (3 month-30year), however the output is provided in a list. I'm looking for a way in which I can produce it in a dataframe (long or wide format) as opposed to a list.

```
library(Knoema)

data <- Knoema('WLDGVTBOND2017', list('timerange' = '01/01/2020-11/29/2020', 'frequency' = 'D', 'Bond' = '3MONTH;2YEAR;3YEAR;5YEAR;6YEAR;10YEAR;15YEAR;20YEAR;25YEAR;30YEAR', 'Country' = 'ZA', 'Indicator' = 'KN.I1'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make the `length` of the `list` elements equal and then use `data.frame`

```
library(Knoema)
out <- data.frame(lapply(data, `length<-`, max(lengths(data))), 
     check.names = FALSE)
```

-output

```
head(out, 2)
#  D - South Africa - 3-Month Bond Yield - Close D - South Africa - 2-Year Bond Yield - Close D - South Africa - 5-Year Bond Yield - Close
#1                                             6                                        6.760                                        7.220
#2                                             6                                        6.765                                        7.255
#  D - South Africa - 10-Year Bond Yield - Close D - South Africa - 20-Year Bond Yield - Close D - South Africa - 25-Year Bond Yield - Close
#1                                          8.21                                         9.985                                        10.055
#2                                          8.26                                        10.045                                        10.115
#  D - South Africa - 30-Year Bond Yield - Close
#1                                        10.040
#2                                        10.095
```

---

By default, the `type` in `Knoema` returns a `ts`.  But, we can change the options of `type` to return either a `xts` or `zoo` or `DataFrame`

```
data1 <- Knoema('WLDGVTBOND2017', 
list('timerange' = '01/01/2020-11/29/2020', 'frequency' = 'D', 
 'Bond' = '3MONTH;2YEAR;3YEAR;5YEAR;6YEAR;10YEAR;15YEAR;20YEAR;25YEAR;30YEAR', 
  'Country' = 'ZA', 'Indicator' = 'KN.I1'), type = 'DataFrame')
```

-output

```
head(data1, 2)
#           South Africa - 3-Month Bond Yield - Close - D South Africa - 2-Year Bond Yield - Close - D
#2020-01-01                                             6                                           NA
#2020-01-02                                             6                                         6.76
#           South Africa - 5-Year Bond Yield - Close - D South Africa - 10-Year Bond Yield - Close - D
#2020-01-01                                           NA                                            NA
#2020-01-02                                         7.22                                          8.21
#           South Africa - 20-Year Bond Yield - Close - D South Africa - 25-Year Bond Yield - Close - D
#2020-01-01                                            NA                                            NA
#2020-01-02                                         9.985                                        10.055
#           South Africa - 30-Year Bond Yield - Close - D
#2020-01-01                                            NA
#2020-01-02                                         10.04
```

It returns a data.frame with row names as the date component

If we need the 'date' as a column

```
str(data1)
#'data.frame':  302 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ South Africa - 3-Month Bond Yield - Close - D: num  6 6 6 6 5.5 6 6 6 6 6 ...
# $ South Africa - 2-Year Bond Yield - Close - D : num  NA 6.76 6.76 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 5-Year Bond Yield - Close - D : num  NA 7.22 7.25 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 10-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 8.21 8.26 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 20-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 9.98 10.04 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 25-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 10.1 10.1 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 30-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 10 10.1 NA NA ...

data1$date <- as.Date(row.names(data1))
str(data1)
#'data.frame':  302 obs. of  8 variables:
# $ South Africa - 3-Month Bond Yield - Close - D: num  6 6 6 6 5.5 6 6 6 6 6 ...
# $ South Africa - 2-Year Bond Yield - Close - D : num  NA 6.76 6.76 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 5-Year Bond Yield - Close - D : num  NA 7.22 7.25 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 10-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 8.21 8.26 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 20-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 9.98 10.04 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 25-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 10.1 10.1 NA NA ...
# $ South Africa - 30-Year Bond Yield - Close - D: num  NA 10 10.1 NA NA ...
# $ date                                         : Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-04" ...
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , any idea on what the best way would be to add a vector of the corresponding dates to the dataframe?

Comment: Perfect solution @akrun ! Thank you so much